# Why putting a script in /etc/cron.hourly is not working?

Tags: scripts, cron

I put an executable script in `/etc/cron.hourly`, but that script didn't run every hour actually it never runs at all.
Here is the script(Hour-sound) that i made:

```
#!/bin/bash
mplayer ~/Music/sfx_msg-highlight.wv &> /dev/null &
spd-say -r -50 -p 50 -t male3  "The time now is $(date +"%l %p")"
notify-send "It's: " "$(date +"%l %p") now." -i ~/Pictures/"first tee.png" -t 5000
```

My crontab is:

```
DISPLAY=":0.0"
XAUTHORITY="/home/naruto/.Xauthority"
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"

0 * * * * /home/naruto/Hour-sound.sh
```

While the `mplayer` and `spd-say` commands are run correctly, the `notify-send` is not. I also tried redirecting error to a file:

```
0 * * * * /home/naruto/Hour-sound.sh 2>/tmp/error
```

But that showed no output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: just making sure, did you make the script executable? owned by root? what happens when you run the script from terminal or put a simple script there? does `/etc/crontab` has the `run-parts` line for running hourly `cron` jobs from the directory?

Comment: Executable: yes, running the script goes well nothing wrong from the /etc/cron.hourly directory, don't know how to check this?is it in the Startup Applications? @heemayl

Comment: Does the `/etc/crontab` file have the line `17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly` ?

Comment: Here @heemayl
http://www.mediafire.com/view/7tqg7cr24xc7q0y/Selection_016.png

Comment: That seems alright..did you notice anything in `/var/log/syslog` ? i am guessing this might be an environment issue..

Comment: Replace the "~" with the absolute path. eg.: `/home/<your_username>/Music/sfx_msg-highlight.wv`

Comment: Please [don't post screenshots of text](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Especially when that text is displayed in a transparent terminal window and includes distracting colors.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As you've probably seen in the comments to your question, the cronjobs in `/etc/cron.hourly` (and the other, similar directories) are executed by `run-parts`. `run-parts` is a little picky about filenames. By default it doesn't execute files whose filenames contain anything other than (all of those from ASCII)

- uppercase letters
- lowercase letters
- digits
- underscores
- dashes ("minus signs")

So if your script has a filename of for example "myscript.sh", it just is ignored, because `run-parts` does not like the dot.

Comment: 1- Here is my files: http://www.mediafire.com/view/rg8r85xb7qw26zs/cron.hourly_017.png
2- Did you try any script in /etc/cron.hourly and worked with you?

Comment: I just tested a litte script that just wrote "Hello" to a file in /tmp, and it worked without a problem. Just in case, you are aware that the scripts in `/etc/cron.hourly` are not necessarily executed "on the hour"? If your cronjob in `/etc/crontab` has 17 at the minutes position, the scripts are executed at 00:17, 01:17 and so forth.  And again just in case, the script's permissions allow the user root to execute them?

Comment: Yah but that script of mine never runs at any time.
and about the permission see here: http://www.mediafire.com/view/psnb4bflawdlyly/naruto@naruto-Inspiron-N5110_-etc-cron.hourly_018.png

Comment: Maybe it's actually a permission problem. I know that scripts in the more general `/etc/cron.d/` must not have write or execute permissions for "group" or "others". "owner" needs execute permission, "group" and "others" must have only read permission. Maybe that applies to `/etc/cron.hourly` as well, though I didn't test that.

Comment: Ok then i have changed the permission for my file http://www.mediafire.com/view/s2lq63u7z54ohbo/naruto@naruto-Inspiron-N5110_-etc-cron.hourly_019.png
that makes the group which is the root group read only and others, so is this going to make any problems?

Comment: Ohh, the same didn't work.

Comment: If the answer above did not solve your problem (you, viewer of this comment), I've aggregated a list of things to check that may help you: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/487471/307715

Answer (score 6):

One problem is that you're trying to run a graphical application (`notify-send`) from cron. That takes  a little tweaking. You need to set `XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY` variables in the crontab so that it can connect to your running X session and you need to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` so it can connect to your pulseaudio session. Unfortunately, these need to be set in the crontab itself, so you can't use `/etc/cron.hourly`. Instead, run `crontab -e` and add these lines:

```
DISPLAY=":0.0"
XAUTHORITY="/home/YOURUSERNAME/.Xauthority"
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"

0 * * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Change the value of  `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to whatever is returned when you `echo` them from a terminal. On my system, this is:

```
$ echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
/run/user/1001
```

It will probably be the same on yours, but check first. Now, your script will run every hour and should work as expected.

Comment: Is that what you mean http://www.mediafire.com/view/ucjpvu8b41n3hue/crontab_(-etc)_-_gedit_021.png . this didn't work for me.

Comment: I think if the problem was in the notify-send then why other command didn't run as well (like mplayer)?

Comment: @BlackBlock there are multiple problems. i) `notify-send` needs the `XAUTHORITY` and `DISPLAY` variables to be set and ii) `mplayer` needs the `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` to be set. Did you try my suggestion? That should fix both issues. You probably also had naming problems because of `run-parts` as explained in the other answer.

Comment: Then why this didn't work for me ? i'm gonna be mad! see my image in 1st comment on your answer

Comment: @BlackBlock no! You are editing `/etc/crontab`, don't do that. You want this to be run as your user, not as root and that file has a different format anyway. Just do what I said in my answer, run `crontab -e` and add the lines there.

Comment: didn't work too, what is going on i feel like my Ubuntu version is screwed up.

Comment: @BlackBlock please edit your question and add the exact files you have created. Both the script and the crontab (show that by running `crontab -l`).

Comment: Hay man it works, but the `notify-send` command didn't show anything.

Comment: @BlackBlock ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) so we can debug this.

Answer (score 4):

A script ending with `.sh` is not executed in `/etc/cron.hourly` folder:

> https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=308911
>   Links or binaries inside a directory handled by run-pars (like
>   /etc/cron.daily) will not run if a **period** is part of their name.

rename the script

```
mv /etc/cron.hourly/Hour-sound.sh /etc/cron.hourly/Hour-sound
```

or put the script-call into

```
/etc/crontab
```

which allows the `.sh` ending

Answer (score 1):

Don't use script with extension (abc.sh) and add your need place. (cron.hours).

add your code stuff to abc file and save.(for your need) (this should be bash command)

use

```
sudo chmod +x abc
```

command to make executable file.

```
edit etc/cronrtab file
```

there has a predefined few lines.edit from your minutes to hours line and save it.

then it will run properly.

Answer (score 1):

An addition to the accepted answer.

You can test your scripts under `/etc/cron.*` first to ensure it will be executed.

Example, you have this script: `/etc/cron.hourly/sample-script`. Execute the below command to check if it is accepted by `run-parts`:

```
run-parts --test /etc/cron.hourly
```

The output should be something like this:

```
/etc/cron.hourly/sample-script
/etc/cron.hourly/some-other-script
...
```

If your script is listed in the output, then you're good to go.