# Showing a message with Crontab

Tags: command-line, shutdown, cron, sh

We are looking for a solution that every day of the week, the pc does a shutdown at 8 p.m.

The pc has multiple user accounts but always only one person will be using it. There will be several accounts because of the different jobs inside the company.

Ex. Person 1 uses Account A , but Person 2 , who has her own pc , but with the same image, logs on to another account because she has a different function. Person 1 only nows the login to his account and person 2 also only for her account. So 1 pc, several accounts but still one user at a time.

Using Crontab (in the admin account) was the best way to let this work for all users.
Now we also want that at 7.50 pm a message (like alert or notify send, or zenity) appears to warn the user of the shutdown. (WHO WILL NOT BE ABLE TO PREVENT IT).

I know it's not possible to ask Crontab for `* * * * * /path/to/notify-send "Pc will shut down".`
We tried a `.sh` with following code :

```
   #!/bin/sh
   DISPLAY=:0.0
   /usr/bin/notify-send 'shutdown warning'
```

(The shutdown warning is not what we want but just for the test'.

We tested this .sh in the terminal and with no errors. Works perfectly.
When we add it to the Crontab , like this:

```
  sudo contrab -e

  * * * * * /home/administrator/sluiten.sh
```

(and yes this is 100 percent sure the correct directory) it doesn't work.

So can someone please tell me what my `.sh` file should look like and how to add it to crontab so it works?

Comment: Is this for a single user system? Does the message need to appear to *all* users?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not adding it to the question. Yes, for multiple users.

Comment: OK, and whose crontab will be running? Will it be root's trying to connect to all active X sessions? Will it be each user's?

Comment: The admin account is the one where changes are made for every user. So this is the account where we want to save the .sh and let it run for all users.

Comment: Is that `root` or just a regular user with `sudo` access?

Comment: user with root.

Comment: So you are going to add this to the crontab you see when running `sudo crontab -e`? Also, please [edit] your question to add all these details. Comments are easy to miss and can be deleted without warning.

Comment: Oke i will. And yes adding this to sudo crontab -e.

Comment: Thanks. Make sure to clarify that this will need to be added to one crontab but has to notify N users who can be using the machine simultaneously. Which, by the way, also means you need to get a list of logged in users, right?

Comment: Not that i am aware of. By my knowledge does the shutdown command work for all users so why not the message? We are installing Ubuntu on more than 100 devices so every device will be the same image.

Comment: No, wait, will these be different machines with one user each or one machine with many users? I am asking if this message will need to be shown to more than one user simultaneously *on the same machine*. Please [edit] your question and explain the entire setup. It is very hard to understand if I need to ask for every detail in a  comment.

Comment: Done! Hope this is better.

Comment: Hi, sorry, I had indeed forgotten about this. I'm still having trouble understanding whether this needs to be shown to multiple users or not. I mean, on machine X, does it just need to be shown to userFoo, or also to userBar and userBaz at the same time? To make it work for the user who owns the crontab, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/611336/85695). You need to set `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `XAUTHORITY` mas well as `DISPLAY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example script to get all users logged in and send a warning to them. After the first time the script is run the log must be checked to see if the cut field needs adjustment, due to potential differences in `who`'s output. On subsequent uses the logging echo lines can be commented out. The while loop is overkill for a single user system but may prove useful.

```
#!/bin/bash
###
USERLIST=($(who | sed -e 's/[)(]//g' -e 's/  */ /g' | cut -d ' ' -f1,5 | sort -u | tr -d '\n'))
LOG=/tmp/"$(basename $0)".log
###
echo "$(who | sed -e 's/[)(]//g' -e 's/  */ /g')" >> $LOG
echo "${USERLIST[@]}" >> $LOG
C=0
while [ $C -lt ${#USERLIST[@]} ]
    do
        D=$((C + 1))
        export DISPLAY="${USERLIST[$D]}"
        export XAUTHORITY="/home/${USERLIST[$C]}/.Xauthority"
        export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u ${USERLIST[$C]})
        /usr/bin/notify-send 'shutdown warning'
        C=$((C + 2))
    done
```

Answer (score -2):

First, `root` crontabs are not like user crontabs, and are NOT edited with `sudo crontab -e`. Read the original `/etc/crontab` file. `root` cronjobs are stored in `/etc/cron.d`, `/etc/cron.daily`, `/etc/cron.hourly` `/etc/cron.monthly`, and `/etc/cron.weekly`. They are controlled with a differently formatted `/etc/crontab` (it has a `userid` field), not the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root` file created by `sudo crontab -e`.

To answer your question, see `man shutdown`:

```
xenial (8) shutdown.8.gz
Provided by: upstart-sysv_1.13.2-0ubuntu21_i386 

NAME
       shutdown - bring the system down

SYNOPSIS
       shutdown [OPTION]...  TIME [MESSAGE]

DESCRIPTION
       shutdown arranges for the system to be brought down in a safe way.  All
       logged-in users are notified that the system is going down and,  within
       the last five minutes of TIME, new logins are prevented.
```

Comment: No, `sudo crontab -e` will actually edit root's crontab. The ones you are referring to exist and are indeed different but aren't root's crontab. Root is just another user, after all, with a personal cron file which you are free to use. That said, the question is about showing a GUI notification every day at a given time. While `shutdown` does indeed use `wall` to send a notification to all logged in users, that won't work on the GUI. The user isn't asking how to shut down a system.

Comment: Yep , thats what i want to know. How to get the message tot pop up, everey day, at the same time for whatever user is logged on. ...; Still looking ...

Comment: @RUS it can be done. You need to write a script that i) gets the currently logged in user; ii) reads their `DISPLAY`, `XAUTHORITY` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` variables; iii) passes them to the crontab (either in the scipt or the crontab itself). I will try and write something if I have time later today but start looking into this yourself in the meantime. Alternatively, just add that crontab to every new user automatically.

Comment: Oke , seems possible.

Comment: @terdon You found the time? Still not been able to make it work...